# FFmpeg: Unable to find suitable output format for [custom format]

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a file using the following command

```
ffmpeg.exe -i .\kme9le9xeaa31.png -c:v apng .\kme9le9xeaa31.png.cpy
```

But ffmpeg yields the following error that it is unable to determine output file format

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for '.\kme9le9xeaa31.png.cp'
.\kme9le9xeaa31.png.cp: Invalid argument
```

Considering that filename is just metadata and should not be taken at face value, should ffmpeg not interpret it? If not, how do you disable such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set output format explicitly, adding `-f png` before `.\kme9le9xeaa31.png.cp`. If `-f` is not set, ffmpeg will examine the filename for an extension and guess the format based on that. In your case, you have changed the extension to `cp` (the letters after the final dot), so ffmpeg can't guess the format. There's no way to set the output format based on the input.

Comment: Fair enough. Guess I have overlooked this in the documentation.

Comment: This helped me trouble shoot a typo in my extension.